# Debug Toolbar in Codeigniter 4 not working

Tags: php, debugging, codeigniter-4, kint

I installed Codeigniter 4.0.2 and did following changes:

1- `CI_ENVIRONMENT = development` in .env file

2- `SetEnv CI_ENVIRONMENT development` in .htaccess in public folder

3- Added `$useKint = true;` in main index.php file in public folder

When I open at localhost, welcome page is rendered but no Debug Toolbar is rendered. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Yes you might be missing the step to install Kint and its friends... Your installation may not have the vendor folder, so you need to run "composer install".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This fixed it for me:

1. Rename env file to .env and open it
2. Uncomment line `# CI_ENVIRONMENT = production` and change to the value to `development`
3. Change the `app.baseURL` value to your app's base URL (this seems like the step you missed)

Comment: This seems to be the one that worked for me. I have set the base URL wrong for some reason

Comment: Is there any way i can show debug to only certain role?

Comment: I modified the app.baseURL on the fly (so had to reset it just at the end to still see the toolbar). Also best to just check the documentation: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/testing/debugging.html#enabling-the-toolbar

Answer (score 9):

The debug toolbar will be there in **bottom right cornor** with a ***codigniter code logo***

1. Click that in order to open the debug bar.

[image]

Click the icon you will be able to see debug bar like this.
[image]

Comment: I know it should be there as per documentation, but i dont get any bar or logo :(

Comment: I had the same extact configuration what posted here. It's working fine. Take look at the writable/debugbar/debugbar_*.json file. Check whether any debug logs are wriiten in it.

Answer (score 5):

I got this problem too for 3 days.
Today I solve this problem by make /writable/debugbar/ to 777 (just for development)

> chmod -R 777 [yourappname]/writable/debugbar/

hopefully this gives you and everyone solution

Answer (score 4):

Here are some stuffs you can check with a fresh CI4 installation :

- Your environment is really on development (you can check it in the footer of your welcome page). If not, be sure to set **CI_ENVIRONMENT = development** in your *.env*. Watch out because fresh CI4 doesn't come with a *.env* file but with a *env* file. Be sure to rename it.

[image: footer of welcome page]

- Make sure you have `defined('CI_DEBUG') || define('CI_DEBUG', 1);` in your *app/Config/Boot/development.php* file
- Try to launch your app with the command line `php spark serve` so you can grab some informations about your app accessing the toolbar.

[image: http info about toolbar]

- Make sure you have a variable named `$globals` in app/Config/Filters.php with 'toolbar' as a value of the 'after' key and 'toolbar' being correctly mapped with the toolbar class into `$aliases`

  ```php
      public $aliases = [
              'csrf'     => \CodeIgniter\Filters\CSRF::class,
              'toolbar'  => \CodeIgniter\Filters\DebugToolbar::class,
              'honeypot' => \CodeIgniter\Filters\Honeypot::class
          ];
  ```

  ```php
      public $globals = [
              'before' => [
                  //'honeypot'
                  // 'csrf',
              ],
              'after'  => [
                  'toolbar',
                  //'honeypot'
              ],
          ];
  ```

It can be some starting points, hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You need to "php spark serve" as the documentation say, because debugbar looks for localhost:8080 as in spark set on.

Answer (score 2):

Set the base url properly if you are not using PHP's built-in server

**app/config/App.php**

```
public $baseURL = 'http://localhost/path_to_CI/public';
```

Answer (score 1):

Today I've faced the same issue in my very first attempt to use CI4 (with XAMPP)...
The only one change I've made on the CI4 framework was to rename the env file to .env and then I set CI_ENVIRONMENT = development in .env file

I've found 2 solutions:

- Use the "php spark serve" command to start my project instead of XAMPP
- Point $baseURL in app\Config\App.php to my project's public folder

Hope this helps!
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

in your env file must modify the baseurl with public folder 
`app.baseURL = 'http://localhost/your-app/public'`

Answer (score 1):

I was same issue with installing ci 4.1.5 and solved by this way:

make user .env file exist in project root folder.

rename `env to .env` or create `.env` in project root folder.

set development environment in `.env` file

```
CI_ENVIRONMENT=development
```

set base url in `.env` file

```
app.baseURL = 'http://localhost/project-root/public/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use HTTP protocol and not HTTP**S**.

On `.env` file check the `app.baseURL = 'http://localhost/'`
and **not** `app.baseURL = 'https://localhost'`.

Then, on the browser access it using `http://` and not `https://`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was in app.baseURL
I did put
where my proyect is compbase

```
-- app.baseURL = 'http://compbase'
```

and I changed it to

```
-- app.baseURL = 'http://compbase.test'
```

When you are using laragon

Answer (score 0):

Just add following lines to `app/config/filters.php` and its work like a charm

```
public $collectors = [
    \CodeIgniter\Debug\Toolbar\Collectors\Timers::class,
    \CodeIgniter\Debug\Toolbar\Collectors\Database::class,
    \CodeIgniter\Debug\Toolbar\Collectors\Logs::class,
    \CodeIgniter\Debug\Toolbar\Collectors\Views::class,
     \CodeIgniter\Debug\Toolbar\Collectors\Cache::class,
    \CodeIgniter\Debug\Toolbar\Collectors\Files::class,
    \CodeIgniter\Debug\Toolbar\Collectors\Routes::class,
    \CodeIgniter\Debug\Toolbar\Collectors\Events::class,
];
```

No need of do anything else as per [Document](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/testing/debugging.html?highlight=debug#id5)

Answer (score 0):

Check your code at `App\Config\Filtes.php`.

Use this line of code:

```
public $aliases = [
        'csrf'     => CSRF::class,
        'toolbar'  => DebugToolbar::class,
        'honeypot' => Honeypot::class,
    ];
```

Instead of this:

```
public $aliases = [
      'csrf'     => CodeIgniter\Filters\CSRF::class,
      'toolbar'  => CodeIgniter\Filters\DebugToolbar::class,
      'honeypot' => CodeIgniter\Filters\Honeypot::class,
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem
It solved when I change directory "writeable/debugbar" to 777 (writeable)

CodeIgniter Debut icon will show at to bottom right if if correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine here in CI 4.2.6 and a heavily modified folder structure, `writable` folder set as 775, on a public address too (so no need for spark serve). My issue was that `$baseURL` was pointing to the address with `http://` instead of `https://` for a typo, so the Chrome inspector helped me out to track it down.

Changing that in App.php, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I've set `app.baseURL = 'http://localhost/project-root/public/'` but used `http://127.0.0.1/project-root/public/` on my browser URL -> No toolbar. Change URL to `http://localhost/project-root/public/` and toolbar appears

Answer (score 0):

In your .env file, update the following variables

```
CI_ENVIRONMENT = development

app.baseURL = 'http://localhost/<name of your project>/'

app.forceGlobalSecureRequests = false
```

Make sure your project is running in port 8080