# CodeIgniter 4.2 Debug Toolbar not showing

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I installed CI 4.2 on web hosting server and did following changes:

1. app/config/app.php -> public $baseURL = 'http://myurl.com/ci4/public/'
2. myurl.com/ci4/env to .env renamed
3. in .env file uncomment and set its value -> CI_ENVIRONMENT  = development
4. in .env file change app.baseURL value -> 'http://myurl.com/ci4/public/'

still doesnt show up, thanks

Comment: is everything else working?

Comment: yes, looks like everything else working, for now

Comment: Your installation may not have the vendor folder. Did you run `composer install` in your terminal or command prompt already?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debug Toolbar in Codeigniter 4 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60832190/debug-toolbar-in-codeigniter-4-not-working)

Comment: I think, the permission of WRITEPATH needs to be set